# Notification at IAM credentials rotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

An external system is using our AWS service and relies on IAM users for authentication and authorization.

As we know that the IAM credentials rotates itself every month or so and one possible way to update external system's IAM credential is to copy & paste the newly-created credentials there, but this process is error-prone sometimes.

We are thinking about an automatic process where each time when IAM is rotating keys it sends a notification to the SQS/SNS and we have a cron job listens to the them and find the new key and send it to the external service thereafter. I have not find a build-in functionality where it can send notifications at key rotation, anyone has ideas about it?

Thanks.

Comment: AWS IAM credentials do _not_ automatically rotate every month. Have you implemented some process that triggers a rotation?

Comment: yea we have Conduit to handle its automatic rotation.

Comment: In that case, you would need Conduit (or what ever does the rotation) to trigger such a notification. If you know a particular API call that Conduit makes, then you could create an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule** to listen for that API call via CloudTrail and then trigger the notification process. Please note that two sets of credentials can be active on an IAM User simultaneously, so it might be a matter of generating and distributing the new credentials, but only disabling the old credentials after all systems have been updated.